# File is deleted from internal storage when orientation changes

Tags: android

When my app starts for first time, it appears a gridView. When the first item of this gridView is pressed then it opens a new activity which downloads the xml file and when this is done, it shows its details in a custom listview.

The activity stores the file in:

```
data/data/mypackagename/something.xml
```

I made this activity to check if this file exists, so when it's re-opened from main, not to have to download the xml file again. This works fine. When I change the orientation, while this activity is still running and after that I press the back button (in order to go to the main activity), I observe in file explorer in DDMS that the file is deleted!!!

This strange thing really does happen, because when I re-open the activity it downloads again the xml file. What I want to know is that if there is a connection between the orientation change and the changes to the internal storage environment?

I delete the file when I close the app (onDestroy method in main activity), which isn't the cause of the problem, because the file is deleted when the second activity is closed.

- If i don't change the orientation ,press the back button and then re-open the activity the file still exists
- Only if I change the orientation an do the above actions the file is deleted.

Comment: The only thing the orientation change does is stop and destroy your activity and create/start a new one. Do you remove the file somewhere in onStop or onDestroy?

Comment: Check your onConfigChanged, or onStop/onDestroy as stated above, for clues. There's not more we can do without the code.

Comment: "The activity stores the file in" -- the directory you cite is not a valid location. Please use `getFilesDir()` for the root of your internal storage, which will wind up as `data/data/mypackagename/files/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some time to figure it out.

When the second activity changes orientation (e.g. to landscape mode) and then I press the back button, the main activity which was on portrait mode before the creation of the second activity, destroys itself and reopens in order to show in landscape mode (because it comes to the foreground for the first time after the orientation changed). So the file was deleted because the onDestroy method in Main.java was called in order to change its orientation after the second activity was detroyed.